# Erro de IIS quando publicado aplicação

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Quando publico minha aplicação, aparece o seguinte erro:

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This
>   operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Utilizo .Net 4.5 e Mvc 4

O estranho é que se eu criar uma aplicação MVC 4 usando o *basic* e adicionando apenas um *Controller* e uma *View* o erro não aparece.

Esse erro só acontece na hospedagem.

**Edit:**

Após alguns testes descobri que esse erro passa a acontecer quando instalo no `signalr 2` e crio o arquivo `Startup.cs`

Comment: Relacionado -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Detlhes

> No IIS 7, há dois modos de processamento de solicitações para pools de aplicativos: modo integrado e modo clássico. Quando você configurar um pool de aplicativos com modo integrado, o IIS processará solicitações para conteúdo gerenciado com o novo IIS integrado e o pipeline para processamento de solicitações ASP.NET. Quando você configurar um pool de aplicativos com modo clássico, o IIS continuará processando solicitações para conteúdo gerenciado usando o IIS separado e os pipelines para processamento de solicitações ASP.NET. Use o modo clássico apenas para aplicativos que não possam ser executados no modo integrado.

Passo a passo de como proceder.

- Abra o Gerenciador do IIS.
- No painel Conexões, expanda o nó do servidor e clique em Pools de Aplicativos.
- Na página Pools de Aplicativos, clique para selecionar um pool de aplicativos da lista.
- No painel Ações, clique em Configurações Básicas.
- A partir da lista Modo de pipeline gerenciado, selecione `Integrado`

Clique em OK.

[fonte](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Cc725564%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Mas o porque deste erro? Porque veja bem, quando crio um projeto mvc 4 basico e apenas adiciono 1 controller, não dá o erro. Agora em uma outra aplicação que existem mais referencias dá esse erro. Pode ser uma referencia?

Comment: Qual versão do IIS você utiliza  no desenvolvimento e qual versão o hospedeiro utiliza ?

Comment: Desconheço, vou verificar... Mas como tem projeto que funciona e outros não funcionam?

Answer (score 0):

Explorando as possibilidades:

1. Funciona no seu IIS local e não funciona no IIS de hospedagem.
   Então o problema esta no projeto (isto está claro).
2. O erro ocorre instalando o `signalr 2`
   Então o problema está neste componente (Você poderia colocar na sua pergunta o Stack Trace, se possível).
3. System.PlatformNotSupportedException é lançada, conforme disse o David, por causa do Pipeline Mode e segundo a Microsoft, por rodar uma dll em uma plataforma errada (tipo, uma dll 64 bits em uma plataforma 32bist, ou um projeto .Net 4.5 em um site 2.0, ou usar pipeline classico em vez de integrado).

Testes para verificar o motivo do erro:

1. Verifique no seu site local (seu IIS) se esta habilitado para 32bits.
2. Verifique se a dll do Signalr 2 é .Net 4.5 (a mesma do projeto) e se a plataforma da dll é a mesma do projeto (32 ou 64 bits).
3. Verifique se o projeto esta configurado para AnyCpu.

Estes teste são pra garantir que seu projeto (e referencias) estão na mesma plataforma permitida pelo site de hospedagem. Pois a exception é clara, refere-se a problema de plataforma.

"[O Headers propriedade só é compatível com o IIS 7.0 modo de pipeline integrado e pelo menos o .NET Framework 3.0. Quando você tenta acessar o Headers propriedade e qualquer uma destas duas condições não for atendida, uma PlatformNotSupportedException é lançada.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)"